# How do I delete a row with specified index in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How do I delete a row with a specified index in datagridview? So if I want to delete the row with index [2], then how can I do that?

I have tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dg1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (i == 2)//if iteration has reached index 2
    {
        dg1.Row[i].Delete;
    }
}
```

I am using Winforms

Comment: Are you targeting WinForm ? WPF or ASP.Net ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the

```
dg1.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
```

and everything will work. I have done this before.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `RemoveAt` on the `Rows` collection itself:

```
dg1.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the datagridview after deleting the row or use the remove method

```
for (int i = 0; i < dg1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (i == 2)//if iteration has reached index 2
    {
        dg1.Row[i].Delete;
        dg1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

OR

```
for (int i = 0; i < dg1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (i == 2)//if iteration has reached index 2
    {
        dg1.Row[i].Remove();
    }
}
```